# Swift [weak self] for Dispatching on main in a nested closure

Tags: swift, multithreading, dispatch-async

So I read that when running `DispatchQueue.main.async {  }` you don't need to declare `[weak self]`. However, i joined a new project, and stumbled across this:

```
public func dispatchOnMain(execute: @escaping () -> Void) {
    if Thread.isMainThread {
        execute()
        return
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: execute)
}
```

Which is an open global function. From here on, doing something like:

```
class Foo {
    
    func bar() {
        dispatchOnMain {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Will this `dispatchOnMain {` require a `weak self`? And why / why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're way overthinking this. The need for weak self has nothing to do with what thread you're going to be on, and it has nothing to do with dispatch queues. If you're going to be worrying about weak self every time you see a pair of curly braces, you'll be a nervous wreck.

Weak self has to do with whether there will be a **retain cycle**. Retain cycles are caused through  **long term storage of a closure** by an object it captures.

Nothing like that is going on here. When you are just saying "perform this action now", regardless of the thread, no retain cycle arises. So no precautions are necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :). The question was kinda if this `dispatchOnMain` function was classified as a "Long term storage of a closure". As i know that the dispatch.main.async itself is a "perform this action now" as you say. But when you open a closure like that i was confused. And i kinda feel that this function overall doesn't bring much value.

Comment: Well that last sentence is debatable. And you're still not listening to what I'm saying about threads vs storage. And the phrase "open a closure" is pretty meaningless. My advice: You should just work until you get a memory leak, like a view controller that doesn't deinit when it closes. That's when you can think about memory management of closures. Trust me, you'll know it when you see it.

Comment: @Vollan check this [forum thread](https://forums.swift.org/t/why-is-implicit-weak-self-not-the-norm/49232) on using `[weak self]`